# pd.read_pickle read only first row

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I want to print my file.pkl but when i read with read_pickle only first row has been read :

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.read_pickle("./Process.pkl")
```

output :
array(['Var1', 'Var2', 'Vartestsmoo', 'Var3', 'Var4', 'Var5', 'Var6'],
dtype=object)

preview of .pkl :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NA4u.png)

Comment: what is the content of `file.pkl` ?

Comment: @papanito i add a preview of .pkl